# how to make sure nginx is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ssh

I've installed rvm, ruby, rails, passenger, and nginx using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu). However, I've installed it all over ssh connecting with myusername@machine-ssh-url. So now I've started nginx using

```
service nginx start
```

But I'd like to make sure it's working before moving on. The tutorial states "nginx is now on. You can see the exciting “Welcome to nginx” screen in your browser if you point it toward http://youripaddress/". But I'm not sure how to get the IP address of the machine I've ssh'd into, and I'm pretty sure I need to take more steps to allow an internet connection to be established.

I'm rather new to web development and deployment so I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction as to the next steps to make my new nginx webserver accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check if the server is running you can type in your console

```
$ service nginx status
```

to know your ip address just type in your console

```
$ ifconfig
```

you can also use your hostname instead of the ip address , you can type

```
$ hostname
yourhostname.com
```

then try http://yourhostname.com

Comment: Okay, that worked. One question, I get a webpage that says "Welcome to nginx on Ubuntu!". Where is this file? it's not the one in `/opt/nginx/html` since when I edited that one I saw no changes

Comment: try in /var/www/html, if it's not, you can find it in one of your config files, try first /etc/nginx/nginx.conf , then look for "root", otherwise look into included config files